# 'domain\user' in python incorrect backslash handling in a string

Tags: python, sql-server, string, pyodbc, backslash

I am using pyodbc to connect to a MSSQL database with DB credentials that work great.

However for a PoC solution I need to connect to it as a user in a different domain.

I have created a credential dictionary that's being imported into the main script. Below is the snip of the dict with the problematic user:

```
creds = {
...
 'amp': {'u': 'domain\\user' # double backslash to escape the \
...
}
```

And below are my parameters for mssql engine as an f string using values from the creds dictionary.

```
params = quote_plus(f"Driver={driver};Server={creds['amp']['s']};Database={creds['amp']['d']};uid={creds['amp']['u']};pwd={creds['amp']['p']}")
```

This returns the following error:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\\user'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\\user'. (18456)")
```

I have tried:

'domain\user'
r'domain\user', 
hardcoding 'domain\user' in the params string

nothing produces the 'domain\user' to allow conection to the DB.

When I go through SSMS I can connect without any problems using same account.

PS. I have gone through numerous question on stack before posting, spoke to a python friend, no luck.

PS2. Stack seems to have assigned this question to sql server as opposed to python? Sorry!

Ok, I have made it work by using `Trusted_Connection=yes` in my params, but the question still remains. How to type domain\user strings to be able to use those?

```
params2 = quote_plus(f"Driver={driver};Server={creds['amp']['s']};Database={creds['amp']['d']};Trusted_Connection=yes")
ampengine = sql.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a Windows/Domain account you must be logged in as that account. SQL Server doesn't allow you to connect as a user you are not logged in as unless using SQL Authentication.

This is assuming mixed-mode authentication is enabled on your server. You will need to either create a SQL user for this user, or connect from their domain whilst logged in as them.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. First bit is true, can be bypassed by running SSMS (and now that I think of it, the script) as a different user in Windows, though. I will try launching the script as that user and enable trusted connection in my mssql engine.

However, the sole question hasn't been answered yet.